Throw php generic from generics trace
I have some method with generic:
 /**
 * @param class-string<T> $class
 * @return T
 * @throws ClientException
 *
 * @template T
 */
private function doSomething(string $content, string $class): object
{
    $response = $this->service->acme($content, $class, null);
    //...
    return $response;
}

In other class ($this->service) I have method with generic to
interface MyService
{
    /**
     * @param class-string<Type> $type
     * @return Type
     * @template Type
     */
    public function acme(mixed $data, string $type, ?string $format): object;
}

But phpStorm and PhpStan cannot correctly recognize the type.
This is the type that phpstorm sees


PHPStan cannot know the type in the function, so it list all the types it has recognized.

Passed @param class-string $type as parameters

Yeah, you passed $class, its value is unknown too.
